# npm install fails "invalid version"

Tags: npm

When trying to install from the package.json, following error occurs

> ```
> >npm install
> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
> npm ERR! Error: Invalid version: "1.0.0.0"
> ```

```
package.json
{
  "name": "version-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0.0",
  "dependencies": { 
      "sample" : "*" 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**TLDR; Semantic Versioning (semver) is enforced.**

To anser the question:

The version number can only be like `\d+\.\d+\.\d+`, so `\d+\.\d+.\d+.\d+` is not valid. Therefore "1.0.0.0" is not valid and and "1.0.0" is. But check the link below for a more accurat description.
This works:

```
package.json
{
  "name": "version-sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": { 
      "sample" : "*" 
   }
}
```

NPM has some [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning). The full documentation of Semantic Versionenig (semver) can be found here https://semver.org/ (including a proper regex)

Short excursion about valid versions:

And this is how the version should be created:

> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
>
> MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner
>
> PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

Here are some sample of semver valid versions:

- 2.0.0
- 2.0.0-rc.2
- 2.0.0-rc.1
- 1.0.0
- 1.0.0-beta

Comment: what the "d" stand for please?

Comment: A digit in sense of regular expression

Comment: I was using 1.0 as the version which was giving me an error. Changing it to 1.0.0 worked. Thanks!

Comment: The pattern @MemLeak can't be complete because "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT" also works fine and it also appears that npm would take anything that starts with three numbers separated by dots but doesn't start with four numbers separated with dots...
But overall the answer is, obviously, to the point

Comment: @Iorweth333: you're right, I've updated the documentation.

Answer (score 17):

## Try this

- Delete the `node_modules` folder
- Delete `package-lock.json` file
- run `npm cache clean --force`

And try installing again using `npm install`

Comment: Now a day the lock file is `package-lock.json`. Thanks for the steps.

Comment: Definitely had the `0.0.0` and was going nuts trying to figure it out.  I feel like "Delete everything and then try again" is the "Turn it off and turn it back on" trick to making angular work.

Comment: I do not think 0.0.0 causes any issue here.  I have a new project that works fine with that version number

Answer (score 13):

"1.0" is not a valid version as defined by Semantic Versioning. Changing it to "1.0.0" should solve your issue.[image]

Comment: For those who want the gory details of what is SemVer compliant: https://semver.org/

Answer (score 5):

My problem solved by updating my npm.
`npm update`