# Errors with installing gulp

Tags: installation, gulp

I am trying to install Gulp and gulp-util

This is what i am getting

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--save-dev',
1 verbose cli   'gulp-util' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.6.0
4 verbose install initial load of C:\Users\icer\Desktop\github\coffeescript\project1\package.json
5 verbose stack Error: Invalid version: "1.0"
5 verbose stack     at Object.module.exports.fixVersionField (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\fixer.js:191:13)
5 verbose stack     at C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:32:38
5 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
5 verbose stack     at normalize (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\normalize-package-data\lib\normalize.js:31:15)
5 verbose stack     at final (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:349:5)
5 verbose stack     at then (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:124:5)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:295:20)
5 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
5 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:303:13)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\icer\Desktop\github\coffeescript\project1
7 error Windows_NT 10.0.14393
8 error argv "C:\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save-dev" "gulp-util"
9 error node v4.6.0
10 error npm  v2.15.9
11 error Invalid version: "1.0"
12 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
12 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. This type of console output is easier to read in a fixed-width font. And "Any thoughts?" and "thanks" are unnecessary.

Comment: thanx for revising.. I was not sure how to organize the log

Comment: Might be related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27543013/6680611). What is the `version` in `C:\Users\icer\Desktop\github\coffeescript\project1\package.json`?

Comment: umm I think i got it! i redid npm init and installed gulp and gulp-util i think they are working :)

will post further if it breaks down .. THANKS!